# How I Get selected value when i edit data [codeigniter]

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, select

How I Get selected value, when i edit data, but i still can choose [codeigniter]

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Jenjang</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="jenjang">
                                    <option value="SD">- SD -</option>
                                    <option value="SMP">- SMP -</option>
                                    <option value="SMA">- SMA -</option>
                                </select>
                                <br/>
                                <?php echo form_error('jenjang'); ?>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you edit it to explain precisely what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: my data is enum, how to get selected data SD or SMP or SMA when i edit  data/update data.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, You can use [Input class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#id5)

```
$selected = $this->input->post('jenjang'); //use get if you are using GET method
```

**Edit** You can use [Form helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_open#form_dropdown)

```
$options = array(
        'sd'         => '-- SD --',
        'sma'           => '-- SMA --',
        'smp'         => '-- SMP --'
);

echo form_dropdown('jenjang', $options, 'sma');  //get this 'sda' value from database
//you can save that value to the database when update/edit form using the way I mention above.
```

Comment: but, how to get selected option from database (in case enum )